# PowerBI Counting multiple values in a column

Tags: powerbi

Data source

```
Column A         Column B

Bill             Fly
Bob              Drive
Tom              Walk
Dave             Fly
Dave             Walk
Bill             Drive
Tom              Drive
```

There will be 8-10 entities in Column A and 3 different values in column B and a total of 200-300 rows. I need to create a visualization (a table, matrix, or multi-row card is what I am thinking) That will show the count of each column 3 value for each entity. So that it would display as

```
         Fly    xx
Bill     Walk   xx
         Drive  xx

         Fly    xx
Tom      Walk   xx
         Drive  xx
```

Anyone know how I could accomplish this and have it display as above (the Column A entity only listed once with the 3 column B values to the right)?

Comment: You may want to try to more clearly show the inputs and outputs that you are using. It's not clear at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for that. The examples of the names and activities displayed differently when I typed the question. I will try to edit and make it more clear

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/New-Matrix-Visual-Hierarchy-Side-by-Side/td-p/247668

Answer (score 0):

Can you check Stepped-layout option in the matrix?

Comment: Thank you. I have it checked and it is displaying as 4 columns with the first being the names and the next 3 being the totals of each of the column B values. It provides the correct information but my supervisors want the column B values stacked on top of each other for each Column A entity (it that's possible)